# Bloquear ips por visita

Tags: php

necesitaba una mano en este tema. Aparentemente el codigo esta bien pero no me esta redireccionando ni bloqueando los ips por el txt.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

/*****************************************************************************
** IP Baneadas de Security Researcher // Security Researcher Banned IP
*****************************************************************************/

```
$ipArray = file("secrech.txt"); 
foreach ($ipArray as $ipTest) {
if (substr_count($ip,trim($ipTest)) != "0") { 
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://myportal2.com">';
die(); }}
```

/*****************************************************************************
** IP Baneadas de Usuarios ya logueados // Banned IP of Users already logged
*****************************************************************************/

```
$ipArray = file("IPBanned.txt");
foreach ($ipArray as $ipTest) {
if (substr_count($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],trim($ipTest)) != "0") { 
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh'
content='0;url=https://myportal.com'>";
die();
header ("Location: index.html"); ?>
```

Comment: Hola, podrías subir también el contenido del archivo "secrech.txt" por favor?

Comment: Esta vacio amigo, creo que registraba unas ips de bots de google